# populate a hashmap with json data from file

Tags: java, json, hashmap, gson

I want to represent [this file](https://github.com/maxlath/wikidata-properties-dumper/blob/master/outputs/properties-en.json) in my java program.

What I want to do is quickly search through it by "key" value, so for instance, given the value `P26` I'd want to return `spouse`.

I thought I could do it in this way:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("properties-es.json")));
        Map<String, HashMap<String, Object>> map = 
        new Gson().fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>>>() {}.getType());
```

And this is to get the value depending on key name

```
String value = (String) map.get("properties").get("P6");
System.out.println(value);
```

But actually when I run the first bit, I get the error:

```
  Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1347 column 10
```

That part of the *a file I modified to simplify the data structure* looks like this:
(^was that a bad idea? is the original file suitable to be represented in a hashmap as I'm describing?)

```
    "P1655": "station number",
    "P1656": "unveiled by",
    "P1657": "MPAA film rating",
    "P1658": "number of faces"

}
```

I did tha because they original [file](https://github.com/maxlath/wikidata-properties-dumper/blob/master/outputs/properties-en.json) seems like it would be a more complex data structure. as I said before, what I want to do is enable the ability to query by those "P values"

It's my idea that a hashmap with P values as keys and words as values would be the best way to do this, but how can I make this happen?

Heretofore I've been using gson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your TypeToken doesn't match the structure of the file contents, specifically that array ("missing").

You could create a data class with the same fields as your file, or keep things simple and just do:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("properties-es.json")));
        Map<String, Map<String, Object>> map = 
        new Gson().fromJson(reader, HashMap.class);
```

You'll get a compiler warning, which can be suppressed, but it should work just fine.

With the data class:

```
// if inner class add "static"
public class Data {
    public Map<String,String> properties;
    public List<String> missing;
}

//...
Data data = new Gson().fromJson(reader, Data.class);
```

Comment: I tried in, and I got this error `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap` but not until I tried to query it by the "P value"

Comment: Oh I forgot to remove that hashmap from the generics. check it again.

Comment: herculean. you are a demi-god. I bow down to your skills!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `"missing"` property has a value that is an array of strings, not an object or array of objects. With the way you are using Gson, it can't do anything with that except throw an error. You'll need to process the `"properties"` and the `"missing"` values separately.

Comment: that's what I was thinking. in fact I'm not interested in the `"missing"`; but could you show me how I might process the `"properties"` I've been trying many different ways but I've not been able to pin it down.